# Markdown with RShiny: Input to Global Enviroment

Tags: html, r, shiny, r-markdown, shinyapps

I'd like to ask the user for a number in the Input and use it in several outputs, as well as in independent chunks on a HTML-Markdown. This would mean that I'd like use for example:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(

    # "Number of Simulations"
    numericInput(inputId = "n",label = "Number of Simulations",
                 value = 100000,min = 1,max = 200000)

)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And then use `input$n` outside the ShinyApp. Is there any way? Maybe a way I was trying to figure is this one:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(

  # "Number of Simulations"
  numericInput(inputId = "n",label = "Number of Simulations",
               value = 100000,min = 1,max = 200000)

)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  reactive({
    setwd("C:/Users/alarc/OneDrive/Escritorio/Experimento")
    save(input$n,file = "brl.RData")
  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But it doesn't work. It's like the shiny app couldn't read the `save` function.

Comment: do you mean once the application reads `n` into the server that you could do something else with it?

Comment: Yes exactly! That’s what I’m looking for

Comment: yeah, you can use the shiny server to do anything you would do in R, so it could source a script and do something, it could write the value to Redis or SQL it could send it to a listener for another application, it could write it to a file. Call whatever packages you need and `curl` or `save` or `write` or `source`

Comment: in theory it could use it as a value to submit to another website and click the button if you used selenium...

Comment: Sounds great but, how would I do it?